# ArcGIS: Compare 'similar' values between multiple tables

Tags: arcpy, relates

I'm looking to see if there's some code out there I can manipulate, or if I can utilize a model to essentially compare field values between 3 or more tables.  The two issues here are

1. I have to relate through an intermediate table to go from the Main table to the various tables I want to compare (more below), and
2. the string values in the main table aren't exactly the same as the values in the compare tables.

Example:
Main_Table has a field *Restricted* with possible values:

- Unrestricted
- Restrict 1
- Restrict 2

Primary Key field *Main ID* relates to a Link_Table with fields: *Main_ID*,  *Table_A_ID* and *Table_B_ID*

Table_A_ID and Table_B_ID may or may not be null.  If they have values, then they relate to their corresponding compare tables (Table A and Table B).

Table A and B both have *Restricted* fields.  But the values here (strings) are either "X" (meaning restricted) or NULL (meaning unrestricted).

Essentially, I want to compare the *Restricted* value in Main_Table to the *Restricted* values of Table A and B.  If there are any differences, I want to either select them in Main_Table or output the results in a new table (whatever is easier.)

So, if Main_Table is 'Restrict 1' (or 2), and either Table A or B is NULL, then they fail and that record is selected in Main_Table (or outputted to a new table).

There's quite a bit involved here and I'm not sure if there's already some code out there I can start with.

**Update 1** I think screenshots would be confusing, as I'm using generic field and table names here in place of my real data.  But I can give you a snapshot of what the tables might look like.  I should note...record 101 has a related value in Table_B but not Table_A.  I still want to compare Main_Table to Table_B in that case, even though there is no related record in Table_A.

[image: Table Examples]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your Question to include a screenshot of some of your records from each table (or an example of them if you prefer not to share your data), and a snippet of any arcpy code you've tried

Comment: You say `X` means "Restricted" in Table_A and Table_B, but you then say that Main_ID `100` is Unrestricted but Table_A and Table_B both return `X` meaning it's Restricted.  How is this a Pass?

Comment: yikes.  In my haste, I introduced a fatal typo.  You are absolutely correct.  If the fields don't match, as is the case with record 100, then it fails.  But that is the record I want to select and/or record in a results table.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction.  It does make a few assumptions that may need to be worked around if incorrect:

- Main_Table is a Feature Layer in ArcMap, the rest are Tables in ArcMap.
- Your only values are `X` or `Null` in the tables, and `Unrestricted` or something else (everything else considered to be `Restricted` in some way).
- If linked records are not found for both Table A and Table B then it will be a Pass
- Needs to be run from ArcMap via a Python Script tool

```py
import arcpy

mainTable = r'MainTable'       # Enter the name of your Main Table here
linkTable = r'LinkTable'       # Enter the name of your Link Table here
tableA = r'TableA'             # Enter the name of Table A here
tableB = r'TableB'             # Enter the name of Table B here

mainIDField = 'Main_ID'        # Enter the name of your Main ID field
tableAIDField = 'Table_A_ID'   # Enter the name of your Table A ID field
tableBIDField = 'Table_B_ID'   # Enter the name of your Table B ID field

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
#mainLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, mainTable)[0]      # Use this line if Main_Table is a Feature Layer
mainLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd, mainTable)[0]   # Use this line if Main_Table is a Table

arcpy.AddMessage(mainLayer.name)
arcpy.AddMessage("Selection Set = {}".format(mainLayer.getSelectionSet()))

mainFields = ['OID@', mainIDField, 'Restriction']
linkFields = [mainIDField, tableAIDField, tableBIDField]
aFields = [tableAIDField, 'Restriction']
bFields = [tableBIDField, 'Restriction']

linkA = dict()
linkB = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(linkTable, linkFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        linkA[row[0]] = row[1]
        linkB[row[0]] = row[2]

tableA_dict = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tableA, aFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        tableA_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

tableB_dict = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tableB, bFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        tableB_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

selectionList = list()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mainTable, mainFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        xOID = row[0]
        xMainID = row[1]
        if row[2] == 'Unrestricted':
            xMainRestrict = 'Unrestricted'
        else:
            xMainRestrict = 'Restricted'
        xARestrict = xBRestrict = "Not Present"

        if xMainID in linkA:
            xLinkA = linkA[xMainID]
            if xLinkA in tableA_dict:
                if tableA_dict[xLinkA] == 'X':
                    xARestrict = 'Restricted'
                else:
                    xARestrict = 'Unrestricted'
        if xMainID in linkB:
            xLinkB = linkB[xMainID]
            if xLinkB in tableB_dict:
                if tableB_dict[xLinkB] == 'X':
                    xBRestrict = 'Restricted'
                else:
                    xBRestrict = 'Unrestricted'

        if (xARestrict not in [xMainRestrict, 'Not Present']) or (xBRestrict not in [xMainRestrict, 'Not Present']):
            selectionList.append(xOID)

mainLayer.setSelectionSet("NEW", selectionList)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

What it does is link all the values together and check if the restrictions in Table_A and Table_B match the restriction in the Main_Table.  If either of them don't, then it adds that record to the selection set.  If a value isn't present in Table_A or Table_B it is overlooked (considered to match Main_Table).

Once every record is checked, it then selects them in ArcMap by passing the list of "Failed" objectIDs through to the layer as a selection set.

Comment: This is terrific.  I need a bit of time to look through this.  I won't be able to do so until next week but I'll try to report back.  I can tell you, however, about a couple of the 'assumptions' you mention.  First, Main_Table is not a feature layer.  It's also a table.  That's important.  Also, you mention that if a value isn't present in tbl A or B, it is overlooked.  That's not going to work in my case either.  If, for instance, A is not present.  Main and B should still be compared.  That's also critical.  But this is at least a very helpful start.

Comment: @MattS - to clarify, if a value isn't present in Table_A then Table_A is overlooked/skipped.  Table_B is still assessed.  Also if Main_Table is a table not a feature layer then a couple of parts may not work so I'll need to make a small adjustment to them.  I'll do that later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I can't thank you enough.  I wasn't expecting this much help but this is great.  My real-life situation is a bit more involved than the scenario I presented here but that's ok.  I can certainly use most of this and just make a few weeks to fit my data and schema a bit better.  Thank you also for updating main_table to a table, not a feature layer.  I very much hope that starting next week, I can sit down and begin testing this code.  I haven't had a chance yet.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Looking forward to your update...

Comment: @MattS I have updated to work on a Table rather than Feature Layer, and fixed a couple of typos in the code

Comment: @MattS let me know if you need help translating to fit your actual data

Comment: thanks.  I noticed one typo so thank you for catching that.  I thought perhaps I wasn't following your code somehow.  I am not going to be able to digest this and work with it for another day or two as I've been out of the office.  However, I will let you know how it goes.  Wish there was a way to PM or email you, though.  Things might get a little screwy when I go to apply it to my real data.  I'm not as advanced a python coder but I 'mostly' follow your code.  Just a few syntax things I'm not familiar with but I think I should be able to get started with this.  super helpful.